# What does Toadette do in Mario Run?

Tags: super-mario-run

I've just finished finally unlocking Toadette -- but while Mario specifies growing with Mushrooms, Luigi jumps higher, Princess does a floaty jump, Toad runs faster, and Yoshi does a flutter jump...I have no clue what Toadette's ability is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> She plays identically to Mario, but unlike Mario, she gets defeated in one hit. Her special ability is converting some Toads to the player's side before the final tally in Toad Rally.

Source: [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Toadette#Super_Mario_Run)

Comment: I just tested this. Her ability is to steal a few toads from your opposition during the tally, possibly swaying the score to your favour. Your still get the same amount of toads, but you get a boost to your score to increase your chances of winning.

Comment: For future reference: this isn't true anymore. All characters now have a small form, so Toadette no longer dies in a single hit.